# Concrete example of S-ideal class group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

For $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, the integer ring of a global field, we denote $S$ to be any set of primes of a global field $K.$ Let
$$\mathcal{O}_{K,S}:=\{x\in K\mid v_{\mathfrak{p}}\geq 0\text{ for }\mathfrak{p}\notin S\}$$ be the ring of $S$-integers of $K$ (see Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg *Cohomology of Number Fields*, Ch. VIII, § 3).

Ideal class group of $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}$ is called **$S$-ideal class group**, denoted by $Cl_{K,S}$.

Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg *Cohomology of Number Fields*, Ch. VIII, § 3, p. 452
states that

> The $S$-ideal class group is the quotient of the usual ideal class group $\mathrm{Cl}_K$ of $K$ by the subgroup generated by the classes of all prime ideals in $S$.

I want to know concrete examples.

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-29})$. Let $S=\{2,17\}$.
$K$ has class number $2$, thus $\mathrm{Cl}_{K,S}$ has order $1$ or $2$.

$\mathrm{Cl}_K$ is generated by $(3,2+\sqrt{-29})$.
Prime ideals in $S$ is generated by $2$ and $17$.
What is the $\mathrm{Cl}_{K,S}$ in this situation?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: In general, Cl$_K,S$ is the quotient of Cl$_K$ by the subgroup generated by prime ideals in $S$.  Since $17$ is inert, it doesn't play any role. The prime ideal above $2$ generaters a class of order $3$, and since $K$ has class number $6$ (not $2$ as you claim), the $S$-class group will be cyclic of order $3$.